# Error drawing curve within slopefield

Tags: asymptote

Note the error in the graphs of the green curve passing through point B and the red curve passing through point C near xmin for the following lines of Asymptote code. Is there a way to correct for this?

```
    import graph;
    import slopefield;
    import fontsize;

    defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
    size(300);
    real dy(real x,real y) {return (y-1)^2*(y+2);}
    real xmin=-2, xmax=5;
    real ymin=-4, ymax=3;

    add(slopefield(dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax),21,black+0.5bp,Arrow));
    draw((-2,1)--(5,1), blue+1bp);
    draw((-2,-2)--(5,-2), blue+1bp);
    pair B=(-1.0,-2.5);
    pair C=(0.0,-1.5);
    pair D=(0.0,2.5);
    draw(curve(B,dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax)),green+1bp);
    draw(curve(C,dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax)),red+1bp);
    draw(curve(D,dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax)),blue+1bp);


    xaxis(YEquals(ymin),xmin,xmax,LeftTicks());
    xaxis(YEquals(ymax),xmin,xmax);
    yaxis(XEquals(xmin),ymin,ymax,RightTicks());
    yaxis(XEquals(xmax),ymin,ymax);
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a known issue with paths which are built incrementally (see the `guide` item of [section 6.2 of the Asymptote user guide](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Paths-and-guides.html)). I can't find a predefined way of forgetting the path control points, but you can always implement a function which would construct a new path from the old path points. The `convpath()` function in the following code does just that:

```
import graph;
import slopefield;
import fontsize;

defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
size(300);
real dy(real x,real y) {return (y-1)^2*(y+2);}
real xmin=-2, xmax=5;
real ymin=-4, ymax=3;

add(slopefield(dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax),21,black+0.5bp,Arrow));
draw((-2,1)--(5,1), blue+1bp);
draw((-2,-2)--(5,-2), blue+1bp);
pair B=(-1.0,-2.5);
pair C=(0.0,-1.5);
pair D=(0.0,2.5);

path convpath(path p) {
    guide res;
    for(int t=0; t<=length(p); ++t)
        res = res .. point(p, t);
    return res;
}

draw(convpath(curve(B,dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax))),green+1bp);
draw(convpath(curve(C,dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax))),red+1bp);
draw(curve(D,dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax)),blue+1bp);

xaxis(YEquals(ymin),xmin,xmax,LeftTicks());
xaxis(YEquals(ymax),xmin,xmax);
yaxis(XEquals(xmin),ymin,ymax,RightTicks());
yaxis(XEquals(xmax),ymin,ymax);
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! New to using Asymptote,  I suspected that this was a known issue, but didn't know where to look.  Very good.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give a complement and a different solution.
I think that the problem is related to the method and a numerical issue.

The routine `curve` uses Runge-Kutta 4th order method to construct the curve and also the control point (more or less it is the derivative in each point). 
Since `y=-2` is the frontier between two different zones, if the stepsize is not sufficiently small, the `S3` (or k4 in the RK4 method) computed is in the decreasing area while the computed point is in the increasing area and as a consequence you have this strange behavior. You can also observe a visible difference with a smaller stepsize.

I modify the `curve` routine with an optionnal `stepfraction` argument, see `mycurve` routine in the following code.

```
    import graph;
    import slopefield;
    import fontsize;


    path mycurve(pair c, real f(real,real), pair a, pair b, real stepfr=0.05) 
    {
      real step=stepfr*(b.x-a.x);     
      real halfstep=0.5*step;
      real sixthstep=step/6;

      path follow(real sign) {
        pair cp=c;
        guide g=cp;
        real dx,dy;
        real factor=1;
        do {
          real slope;
          pair S(pair z) {
            slope=f(z.x,z.y);
            return factor*sign/sqrt(1+slope^2)*(1,slope);
          }
          pair S3;
          pair advance() {
            pair S0=S(cp);
            pair S1=S(cp+halfstep*S0);
            pair S2=S(cp+halfstep*S1);
            S3=S(cp+step*S2);
            pair cp0=cp+sixthstep*(S0+2S1+2S2+S3);
            dx=min(cp0.x-a.x,b.x-cp0.x);
            dy=min(cp0.y-a.y,b.y-cp0.y);
            return cp0;
          }
          pair cp0=advance();
          if(dx < 0) {
            factor=(step+dx)/step;
            cp0=advance();
            g=g..{S3}cp0{S3};
            break;
          }
          if(dy < 0) {
            factor=(step+dy)/step;
            cp0=advance();
            g=g..{S3}cp0{S3};
            break;
          }
          cp=cp0;
          g=g..{S3}cp{S3};
        } while (dx > 0 && dy > 0);
        return g;
      }

      return reverse(follow(-1))& follow(1);
    }


    path mycurve(pair c, real f(real), pair a, pair b, real stepfr=0.05)
    {
      return mycurve(c,new real(real x, real y){return f(x);},a,b,stepfr);
    }


    path convpath(path p) {
        guide res;
        for(int t=0; t<=length(p); ++t)
            res = res .. point(p, t);
        return res;
    }

    defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
    size(300);
    real dy(real x,real y) {return (y-1)^2*(y+2);}
    real xmin=-2, xmax=5;
    real ymin=-4, ymax=3;

    add(slopefield(dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax),21,black+0.5bp,Arrow));
    draw((-2,1)--(5,1), blue+1bp);
    draw((-2,-2)--(5,-2), blue+1bp);
    pair B=(-1.0,-2.5);
    pair C=(0.0,-1.5);
    pair D=(0.0,2.5);

    draw(convpath(curve(B,dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax))),green);
    draw(mycurve(B,dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax),0.02),lightgreen);
    draw(mycurve(C,dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax),0.02),lightred);
    draw(convpath(curve(C,dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax))),red);
    draw(mycurve(D,dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax)),blue+1bp);


    xaxis(YEquals(ymin),xmin,xmax,LeftTicks());
    xaxis(YEquals(ymax),xmin,xmax);
    yaxis(XEquals(xmin),ymin,ymax,RightTicks());
    yaxis(XEquals(xmax),ymin,ymax);
```

And the result

[image]